# How to check if UrlImage is null in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

I am loading image from a URL and it's works as expected.
Scenario when the URL no longer valid, i.e if the image was deleted and I do see the default image displays since I created EncodedImage from the Label icon.

I would like to know if there is anyway I can check if the image has actually loaded from the URL?

What I want to achieve is set a different image to a background if the URL image is not found.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing is to check if the URLImage's `isAnimation()` method returns `true`. If it returns true, then the actual image hasn't been loaded yet.  If it returns false, it means that the image is already loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Which system do you use to download the image ? Is the image stocked in the Storage, in the FileSystem ?

If you have dowloaded the image using the ConnectionRequest, you may override it's handleErrorResponseCode method and do something when you have the network error code corresponding to no image ( i.e. 204 : no content).

Comment: Hi Gauvain, I am loading the image from s3 bucket with url.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are many workarounds for this problem. I use this jQuery one

Comment: Savan and Christian, thank you fro the responses.  This question was tagged to Codename One (Mobile).

Comment: Down voted because this question was tagged Codename One, not Javascript.